# Проблема в YMaps.Events.observe

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Приветствую. Прошу помощи. Не работает YMaps.Events.observe. Теперь по порядку.

```
var polygonData = [
    {
        url : Некий урл,
        poly : [
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133853,53.191915),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133901,53.191982),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133874,53.191989),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133976,53.192108),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133965,53.192114),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133976,53.192127),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.13396,53.192134),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134314,53.192585),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134464,53.192553),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134475,53.192566),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.13455,53.192546),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134539,53.19253),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.1347,53.192498),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134716,53.192508),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134786,53.192491),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134791,53.192479),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135033,53.192417),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135049,53.192427),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135124,53.192411),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135119,53.192401),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135392,53.192324),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135408,53.192334),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135478,53.192321),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135478,53.192305),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135612,53.192288),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135596,53.192263),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135612,53.192247),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135618,53.192069),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135532,53.191973),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135414,53.192002),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135398,53.191982),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135221,53.192028),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135226,53.192047),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135172,53.192066),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.135162,53.19206),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.13455,53.192205),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134555,53.192221),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134443,53.192243),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134137,53.191844),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134142,53.191821),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.13411,53.191783),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134116,53.191721),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.134083,53.191673),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133858,53.191725),
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(50.133853,53.191915)
        ]
    },
```

];
Это была подготовка данных для создания полигона. 
Теперь создаем собственно сам полигон.

```
            p = new YMaps.Polygon(pd['poly'], {
            style : 'polygon#Normal',
            hasHint: 0,
            hasBalloon: 0,
            interactive:"NONE"

        });
```

Вот. ниже по коду вешаю на созданный полигон эвенты. Типа MouseEnter, MouseLeave, Click.
Вот так:

```
            YMaps.Events.observe(p, p.Events.Click, function (polygon, mEvent){
            // console.log(mEvent);
        });
```

Проблема в следующем. Работает на десктопе, и на iphone, а вот на android полигон не реагирует на эвенты.

Comment: UPD. 
Выяснилось еще вот что. На андроиде вообще не отрисовывается дополнительный слой на карте. Если на iphone  поверх карты есть еще svg с координатами полигонов, то на андроиде их нет.  Почему такая разница в работе?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вы используете версию 1.х, которая давно deprecated. Она не развивается и в ней не добавляется поддержка новых устройств/браузеров. 
Перейдите на версию 2.1,  там такой проблемы не будет.
Пример: [как создавать полигоны](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon?from=SO) и [как работать с событиями](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_properties?from=SO)

Comment: @Reni, да, вы правильно понимаете. Просто до последнего пытался найти способ обойтись без перехода. Слишком много там переписывать. Но видимо придется. Спасибо за ссылки на документацию.